# custom gradle pluginin cause "Multiple dex files define XXX" exception

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle-plugin

I defined a gralde plugin using transform api,but when I compiling app with it,the jars under the directory build\intermediates\transforms\myplugin cannot be deleted,and throws exception like this:

```
Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause:com.android.dex.DexException:Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/XXXX;
```

The only way to delete jars is to exit android studio and delete that from file system.

what can I do to fix this？

Comment: try to delete whole build folder and then clean build project

Comment: yeah，but this happens very offen ，I cann’t delete those jars manualy every time

Comment: may be your jar version and app dependency are conflicting.. try to add jar that match app dependancies

Comment: the point is not dependncy conflicting but the jars that myplugin handled cannot be deleted.so the same jars apppear times in the directory,and clean the project is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

My  customized gradle plugin used gradle-transform api and javassist to edit bytecodes in java. javassit persists a classPool that hold all jar-files and other classfiles in it.so the resolution :to clear the pool after compiling:

```
private static javassist.ClassPool pool;
private static List<ClassPath> paths;
public static void addPath(String path){
    ClassPath classPath = pool.appendClassPath(path)
    paths.add(classPath);
}
public static void clearPath(){
    pool.clearImportedPackages();

    if(paths != null && paths.size()>0){
        for(ClassPath path : paths){
            pool.removeClassPath(path)
        }
        paths.clear()
    }
    pool = null;
}
```